# How to use std::stod properly

Tags: c++

I am working on writing a simple linear line calculator. For example, a user can enter two equations (strings) such as y=5x+3 and y=-3x+6. The most basic feature of this calculator is that it will return the intersection point of these two lines.

The obstacle I can't seem to figure out is how to parse the string into two pieces of data: the slope, and the y-intercept. This is a simple calculator, so the format of both lines will be y=mx+b, however, both the slope and/or y-intercept may be non-integer numbers (i.e. floats).

I came across a function in the string library called stod, which converts a number in a string to a numerical value (am I understanding this correctly?).

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/stod/

My question is, will this function do the job? If so, how exactly do I use the "idx" parameter? I don't quite understand it.

If this isn't going to work, how can I parse this user-entered data?

- both equations are strings (y=mx+b)
- m and b have private variables dedicated in storing the decimal value (i.e. double m_ and double b_ are private member variables)

Comment: How picky can you get with the input? Can you demand that the input is always **exactly** of the form `y=mx+b`?

Comment: Sort of. Like I said, they enter exactly "y=mx+b", which I guess could be rearranged to "y=b+mx" but the slope is always associated with the x. The big variance is the slope/intercept values. They are doubles, so a user can enter -5, 5.2, -0.5, etc...

Comment: @nickfoss32, the example code in your linked page shows how to use the `idx` parameter.

Comment: I'd probably use `scanf`, something like `scanf("y = %f x + %f", &m, &b);`, and either reject input of the form `y=b+mx` or else (if the first one failed to convert two items) try `scanf("y = %f + %f x", &b, &m);`

Comment: I would use C++ streams to my advantage in this case! C++ streams will be able to put data directly into floating point numbers!
std::cin >> double x;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is how the idx parameter works:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main(void)
{
    std::string data = "y=5.9568x+3.14"; //say you have a string like this..

    double y, x, m, b;
    y = 0;
    x = 0;

    std::size_t offset = 0; //offset will be set to the length of characters of the "value" - 1.
    m = std::stod(&data[2], &offset); //So we want to get the value "5.9568
    b = std::stod(&data[offset + 3]); //When we reach this line, offset has a value of 6

    std::cout<<b;
    return 0;
}
```

So now you're asking why does it have a value of 6? Well because:

5.9568  is exactly: 6 characters in length. Thus on the next line when we do

`b = std::stod(&data[offset + 3]);`

we are actually feeding it a pointer to address of `x` + 3.. and that turns out to be right at the beginning of the `3.14`.

In other words it's equivalent to:

`std::stod(&data[9]);`

So that idx parameter is actually the index/length of the double in characters within the string. If the string is:

`str = "3.14159"`

Then `std::stod(str, &idx)` will make idx equal to: 6.

if the string is:

`str = "y = 1024.789"` then `std::stod(&str[4], &idx)` will make idx equal to: 8 STARTING FROM &str[4]..

Comment: In general, should this be wrapped in a try/catch(invalid_argument) handler?

Answer (score 0):

Here's something simple with no error checking to get you started:

Assuming your input string is always exactly of the form `y=mx+b` and you wish to parse it to obtain the numerical values of `m` and `b` you can first tokenize the string with `y`, `=`, `x`, and  as delimiters.

An example of a tokenizing function can be found [here](http://code.google.com/p/quirkysoft/source/browse/bunjalloo/bwt/source/string_utils.cpp?spec=svn5c29c2bd2a76b6f05541a273b9e5357ef33697a4&r=ba7e2979928fa2c92b3596bd769d7149fed272e9). Here it is reproduced:

```
void tokenize(const std::string &str,
              std::vector<std::string> &tokens,
              const std::string &delimiters)
{
  // Skip delimiters at beginning.
  std::string::size_type lastPos = str.find_first_not_of(delimiters, 0);
  // Find first "non-delimiter".
  std::string::size_type pos     = str.find_first_of(delimiters, lastPos);

  while (std::string::npos != pos || std::string::npos != lastPos)
  {
    // Found a token, add it to the vector.
    tokens.push_back(str.substr(lastPos, pos - lastPos));
    // Skip delimiters.  Note the "not_of"
    lastPos = str.find_first_not_of(delimiters, pos);
    // Find next "non-delimiter"
    pos = str.find_first_of(delimiters, lastPos);
  }
}
```

The first argument is the string to tokenize, the second is a reference to a `vector<string>` which the function will put the tokens in, and the third argument is a string containing all the delimiter characters. You can use it with the delimiters mentioned above like this:

```
string s = "y=-3x + 10";
vector<string> tokens;
tokenize(s, tokens, "y=x ");
```

For the example string above `tokens` will contain the following strings: `-3`, `+`, and `10`.

Now you can iterate over `tokens` and call `stod()` on each token. You can put the results of `stod()` in a `vector<double>`:

```
vector<double> doubles;
for (vector<string>::iterator iter = tokens.begin(); iter != tokens.end(); ++iter) {
    try {
        doubles.push_back(stod(*iter)); // size_t* idx is an optional argument
    } catch (...) {
        // handle exceptions here. stod() will throw an exception
        // on the "+" token but you can throw it away
    }
}
```

Now `doubles` should have exactly 2 elements -- one for the slope and another for the intercept. Assuming the slope came first (the string was of the form `y=mx+b` instead of `y=b+mx`) then you can extract them from `doubles`:

```
double m = doubles[0];
double b = doubles[1];
```

Parsing the initial string is more complicated if the user is allowed different forms like `y=b+mx` (in that case the intercept came first), and much more complicated if the user can enter even stranger (but valid) forms like `x*m+b=y` (now you can't just assume that the number before the `x` character is the slope). It's not clear from your question exactly what alternate forms are considered valid, but nonetheless this should get you started.

Finally, as to your question about `*idx`, `stod()` puts into it the position of the first character after the number it parsed. This allows you to easily parse multiple numbers in a single string by skipping the number that was just parsed. Using the example at your reference link with some added comments:

```
std::string orbits ("365.24 29.53");
std::string::size_type sz;     // alias of size_t

double earth = std::stod (orbits,&sz);
// sz now holds the position of the first character after 365.24, which is whitespace
// the next call to stod() will start from the sz position
double moon = std::stod (orbits.substr(sz));
```