# Visual Studio not recognizing stod() even with precompiled headers turned off and<string> included

Tags: c++, c++11

Below is a snippet to show the basic structure of my code right now. On that last line, Visual Studio is saying "no instance of overloaded function that matches the argument list". According to the references I can find from VS help, however, this is exactly how the function should be used. I have string and iostream included, and I have precompiled headers turned off, so I'm not sure if the fault for VS not recognizing this function is on me or not.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

int main(){
    Stack<double> nums;
    std::string input;
    std::string::size_type index;

    std::cin >> input;
    double num = std::stod(input, index);
}
```

Comment: 2nd parameter needs `&`, takes a pointer as it's an output.

Comment: check the docs: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stof

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use std::stod properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26008321/how-to-use-stdstod-properly)

Answer (score 2):

It should be a pointer to size_type. Verified in VS.

```
double num = std::stod(input, &index);
```

When overloading is around, you must be precise :)